# General purpose kindle computing questions allowed?

Tags: support

Can I ask a question about the Kindle with regards to using it as a general purpose computing device, running Linux? My question is about the APIs that might be available to a programmer writing an application to run on Kindle hardware.

It's a little hard to tell from the FAQ, because it contradicts itself. It says that I can ask questions about computers, but not about electronic devices. Well, I haven't seen many mechanical computers around lately. The Kindle fully qualifies as a computer, containing all of the basic parts: CPU, RAM, OP, screen. Just because it is small shouldn't rule it off topic. [This popular answer](https://meta.superuser.com/a/3268/104865) seems to agree.

So I feel like this questions should be OK, but I thought I should ask first.

Comment: While this doesn't answer the titular question, if you want to know what APIs are available you should be asking on [so]. That's where programming questions go. [su] deals with the *use* of systems, not writing software for them.

Comment: You don't indicate which Kindles your talking about, I can only assume, your talking about Kindle Fire which would mean since its based on Android the same API would apply.  I would agree a programming question belongs on Stackoverflow.  While you could stretch the facts and call a Kindle a PC most people wouldn't call it one.

Comment: I don't know if it's *off-topic* here, but you would probably get a better answer on the other site(s)

Comment: @Ramhound - I wouldn't call a Kindle a PC, but I would call it a computer.

Comment: @Rocketmagnet - Superuser is about (personal) computer software and (personal) computer hardware or thats what its suppose to be.  There are SE websites for mobile phones and android devices for a reason.